# Likert Analysis: Using wilcoxon to determine significance between pre and post survey data in R

Tags: r, survey

I have very little experience in statistics, and any help would be greatly appreciated. I am currently using R to do this.

I am trying to determine the significance of likert analysis data. I have one sheet each of our pre and post survey with 25 questions (columns), with responses from 59 students (rows).

I am using the Wilcoxon signed rank test, ie. testing the significance of the first question by comparing the first column from pre survey data with the first column of the post survey data, then the second question, so on and so forth.

How do I write a for loop to run the Wilcoxon test across responses to all questions?

I've found this so far, but haven't been able to run it correctly. Even help with understanding some of the syntax would be great.

```
test.fun <- function(dat, col) { 

 c1 <- combn(unique(dat$group),2)  sigs <- list()  for(i in 1:ncol(c1)) {
    sigs[[i]] <- wilcox.test(
                   dat[dat$group == c1[1,i],col],
                   dat[dat$group == c1[2,i],col]
                 )
    }
    names(sigs) <- paste("Group",c1[1,],"by Group",c1[2,])

 tests <- data.frame(Test=names(sigs),
                    W=unlist(lapply(sigs,function(x) x$statistic)),
                    p=unlist(lapply(sigs,function(x) x$p.value)),row.names=NULL)

 return(tests) }


tests <- lapply(colnames(dat)[-1],function(x) test.fun(dat,x)) names(tests) <- colnames(dat)[-1]
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of running wilcoxon test based on what you'd describe:

Example data: assuming that the response are rated as 1 to 5, the pre and post surveys are kept in separate separately, with matching column names.

```
pre <- replicate(25, sample(1:5, 59, replace=T))
post <- replicate(25, sample(1:5, 59, replace=T))
colnames(pre) <- colnames(post) <- paste0("Q", 1:25)
```

To run wilcoxon test, use lapply function to loop each of column name (x) that will insert the chosen pre[,x] and post[,x] data for the test. Results of all 25 tests return as a list (all.test):

```
all.test <- lapply(colnames(post), function(x) wilcox.test(pre[,x], post[,x]))
```

To extract statistics and p.value for all tests at once, use sapply to loop each wilcoxon test and extract ('[') both "statistics" and "p.value" and return as a matrix.

```
sapply(all.test, '[', c("statistic", "p.value"))
          [,1]      [,2]    [,3]     [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]       [,9]      [,10]    
statistic 1556.5    1931    1718     1894.5    1659      1785      1652.5    2066.5     1912.5    1658     
p.value   0.3122574 0.29259 0.903439 0.3976938 0.6555535 0.8086088 0.6301387 0.07366355 0.3451189 0.6523042
          [,11]     [,12]     [,13]    [,14]      [,15]     [,16]     [,17]      [,18]     [,19]     [,20]    
statistic 1605.5    1723      1678.5   1368       1810      1813      2082        1595      1862.5    1588     
p.value   0.4591325 0.9254467 0.735141 0.04035589 0.7040117 0.6920512 0.06084165 0.4222573 0.5027951 0.4028304
          [,21]     [,22]     [,23]     [,24]     [,25]    
statistic 1986.5    1816.5    1854      1819.5    1859.5   
p.value   0.1772745 0.6779568 0.5344984 0.6661272 0.5147567
```

Comment: It's essentially the same code as you have shared. Just splitting it up to help with understanding what each step does. I'd not run wilcoxon for like ever, so let me know if I'd make a mistake too.

Comment: Nope it definitely worked, I couldn't have done it without your help.

Comment: Hi again, I actually ran into some strange things... I was noticing that a lot of the responses had no significant difference between pre and post. I happened to decide to "run" the code several times, and every time I get a different p-value. Is this sort of like the "=" on the calculator, and will keep running the same loop the more times I run it? (But the changing p values don't seem to have any trend.)

Comment: The command `sample` produce different data every time you run. The pre and post data are thus different every single time,  consequently giving you different sets of p-value.

Comment: How should I change the command if I don't want to change the pre and post data every time? They're paired responses. So I'm trying to take all the pre-survey responses from student 1, for example, and pair it with his/her post-survey responses.

Comment: The pre and post data in the code above is just an example data to replicate your own data. As long as the actual data for each pre and post data have the same structure, i.e. 59x25 matrix, with identical column name for each student across the two data set (e.g. "student1"), the command to run all.test and sapply should work. Alternatively, you can post a sample data for pre and post data, and I can assist to make it run.

Comment: Thanks! Yep I modified your code so that it fit my file names. For example, I ran: 
`pre3 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T, sep = ",")
post3 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T, sep = ",")

pre3 <- replicate(28, sample(1:5, 37, replace=T))
post3 <- replicate(28, sample(1:5, 37, replace=T))
colnames(pre3) <- colnames(post3) <- paste0("Q", 1:28)

all.test <- lapply(colnames(post3), function(x) wilcox.test(pre3[,x], post3[,x]))

sapply(all.test, '[', c("statistic", "p.value"))`

Comment: Sorry that looks like a mess! Anyway, I meant to say I modified the columns and rows to work or my data set, and because this was the third time the students took the pre and post surveys, I called it pre3 and post 3. My question though, was whether this compared the same data sets, and if so, why did it randomize the data in such a way that the p-values would change? Sorry if it's confusing, but thank you!

Comment: Try running without the lines `pre3 <- replicate(28, sample(1:5, 37, replace=T)) ` and `post3 <- replicate(28, sample(1:5, 37, replace=T))`. They were there as demo data, and are not required for your analysis.

Comment: In fact, by adding them in, you are replacing the fake data with the actual data you read in with the `read.csv` command.